# selected value is not coming in angular-ui-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-select

angular select ui is not working properly..

```
[http://plnkr.co/edit/CKHbiSQ4tZXTjOyxpyBK?p=preview][1]
```

Select lists are not working properly.
Not able to work with option.text and option.value.

I want to show selected value in selected but i am not able to.

Comment: there's quite a lot of code in the plunker you made, could you make a smaller example that shows the issue? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define option in the controller. It will solve the issue.

```
$scope.option = {};
```

Here is the pluncker link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Z1oqz2r3Iq5khAF3GVI1?p=preview